# I want to link a subfolder page contents with a page in main folder

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to redirect the login page which is in subfolder `signup` to the index page which is in main `web` folder `web` folder holds both index page or `signup` folder and `login` page is in signup folder.

How can I fix it.

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTTP spec the location header must be an absolute URL, like so:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
```

You could also do this automatically:

```
header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand of your question that is a **Sign-up folder** that consist of `Login page` and you want redirect from login page to `Index page` that is on **Root folder**. if is this you will be use :

```
header('location : ../index.php');
```

Comment: The location header must use an absolute URL.

Comment: Because the spec says so http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30 The fact that most web browsers tolerate relative URIs doesn't make it okay to use them.